How to Use Stretch Layout with Margin for Desktop and Optimal Frame Sizes for Desktop and Mobile
I'm currently working on implementing the site layout grid in Figma. I have a question regarding layout grids for desktop sizes. Instead of setting the type to center, is it possible to set the type to stretch and apply an 80px margin?
These images are from the Figma environment, which can help you better understand my question. One has the type set to "stretch" with the "margin" property, and the other has the type set to "center".


Additionally, what are the most commonly used frame sizes for desktop and mobile layouts?
